# How to render multiple displays in Unity

Tags: rendering, camera, unity

I have a scene (lest assume, large glass table I want to looking through) and I want to render with 4 displays (each 1920x1080). How can I set up camera for this, I want the "glass cube" to fill entire scene (all four displays).

If I use single perspective camera and I want to see entire scene, I got stretched image near sides - in other words only middle is correct and sides are stretch. If I correct this, than my scene is not filling entire window and is small.

I have tried to create single camera for each "display", but this will cause frustums overlapping and I have part of the image rendered twice (logically). I can use orthographic-camera, there is no overlap, but I have no perspective.

How to solve this problem?

**Edit:** I am using Unity 5

Comment: What game engine is this?

Comment: @ZEKE Edit added

Comment: @ZEKE the game engine used is totally irrelevant in this situation, this is an issue that would arise with _any_ engine, even if you built your game entirely with pure OpenGL calls.

Comment: Still, @Alexandre; it doesn't hurt to have a little more information to go on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

Sorry.

Well you could. But it would involve a distortion mesh (basically, you render your scene to a texture, and you distort that texture with a mesh, and you display that mesh). And this would imply that your camera never changes position, or that you have a distortion mesh available for each of the camera's possible positions.

Otherwise, well, you've said it, you'll lose the perspective (because you'll use orthographic cameras).

Maybe a work around I could suggest:

Have all your cameras positioned at the same location, but shooting each a FOV of 45°, and each rotated of 45° from the previous one. You'll cover a wide angle of 180°. This way, you won't be shooting twice the same thing. Now the tricky part is to have your scene "wraped" around your cameras: you'll need a table that does a half circle, and if you move objects width-wise in the scene, you'll have to move them radially instead.

In the image, we see a top view of what I suggest; the black lines are the four fields of view, and the red shows the bent (in a half circle) rectangle long table.

[image: idea]

This would be the best if you could project onto a curved surface, and better if your could set up your four displays in a 180° fashion.

This, of course, will not *solve* your issue, it could only *alleviate* it.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it wont be possible (at least not easy and accurate). Other thing that come to my mind is maybe use ortho-camera and calculate pseudo-projection for models. That way, model will be rendered once, but absed on "quadrant", different projection matrix will be used (or some interpolation between matrices) to handle transition.

Comment: Draw diagrams like the one @Alexandre includes in the answer, and it can help you think about what you want to be visible from different positions. And if it will "make sense" the way you want.

Comment: @MartinPerry If you're very knowledgeable with projection matrices, be my guest to try! But from what I've seen, though, there is no way to 'interpolate' an orthographic projection matrix to a perspective one. I would think you'd encounter _a lot_ of issues if you mix projection matrices for the scene objects as the matrices "move" things around. I'll be eager to see what solution you come up with!